# How to bind json response data to custom class when field name is used as data type

Tags: c#, json

The below snippet is the response data which i'am getting in JSON format.
Now i need to bind these data to custom class. But there is a problem, where one of my field name is **'double'**.Here i can not use double as a field name since it is a C# keyword.
Please suggest how to bind the below data to custom class.

```
{
"guest": {
  "first_name": "Abc",
  "last_name": "Def",
  "email": "abc@def.com",
  "country_code": "+91",
  "phone": "1234567890"
},
"booking": {
  "single": 0,
  "double": 1,
  "extra": 0,
  "checkin": "19/09/2017",
  "checkout": "20/09/2017",
  "hotel_id": "1234",
  "is_provisional":"true",
  "external_reference_id": "asasa"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use `double` or any other keyword as a field name and other named entities. You just need to prefix it with an `@`. In your case `public double @double`

Comment: Thank you, It fixed my problem.

Comment: Mark it as answer :)